# Node.js Selenium wait until text equals

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am attempting to write a function that waits until a text is equal to a certain value. In my `element.js` (which represents all web elements), I wrote this function:

```
getText() {
  return this.browser.getText(this.selector);
}

waitForTextEquals(expectedText) {
  browser.waitUntil(function () {
    console.log(this.getText().toString() + "||" + expectedText)
    return this.getText() === expectedText
  }, 5000, 'expected text to be different after 5s');
}
```

In my mocha script, I have this:

```
it('updates payment due date when issue date and payment terms change', () => {
  invoiceEditPage.details.paymentDueDateField.waitForTextEquals(formatDate(moment(today).add(15, 'days')))
    return invoiceEditPage.details.paymentDueDateField.getText()
    .then((dueDate) => assert.strictEqual(dueDate, formatDate(moment(today).add(15, 'days'))));
});
```

However, this does not cause the program to wait, even though it is synchronous. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: The issue could be with `browser.waitUntil` since this method doesn't belong to protractor. Try with `browser.wait` instead.

Comment: I actually moved my test down so it runs after the text gets changed, so it works for now. Meanwhile, I am dealing with another JS issue...